# Vim visual selection and regexp

Tags: vim

I am having a problem with the visual selection and running a regular expression replace. When I select some text that does not contain the whole row, and hit : to bring the command line up, and do something like

```
:s/T/t/
```

Then the first match on the line (whether it's selected or not) is changed. So, for example, I  have the text

```
Test Text here
```

and I visually select the word **Text**, then run the above substitution, I end up with

```
test Text here
```

which is not what I want.

Any ideas how to achieve the right result?

Edit: The actual command line is

```
'<,'>s/T/t/
```

as defaulted by Vim when you press : with a visual selection.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use \%V (see http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#//%V)

> ```
> \%V   Match inside the Visual area.  When Visual mode has already been
>     stopped match in the area that |gv| would reselect.
>     This is a |/zero-width| match.  To make sure the whole pattern is
>     inside the Visual area put it at the start and end of the pattern,
>     e.g.:
>         /\%Vfoo.*bar\%V
>     Only works for the current buffer.
> ```

So:

```
:s/\%VT/t/
```

If you want to replace multiple hits, add /g

```
:s/\%VT/t/g
```

Comment: according to `:h %V`, you should wrap the whole search pattern in `\%V` if you want to ensure the pattern is inside the selection. Like: `:s/\%Vlongpattern\%V/short/`.

Comment: @m0tive: I did quote the documentation on that. And, when the pattern is as single character that isn't useful

Comment: you're just too quick for me ;-)

Comment: Thanks for that. My actual pattern is more than one character, so learning about \%V was what I needed.